# Import Shapefile to PostGIS in QGIS' DB Manager without using its ID column

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-2, dbmanager

I have a shapefile with a "id" field in which some non-unique ID numbers exist (don't ask).

When I try to import this to a PostGIS database using QGIS' DB Manager, it tries to re-use those IDs are unique primary key and fails.

The "Primary key" option is not ticked. "id" is shown in grey next to it.
[image: screenshot]

How can I make DB Manager ignore an existing "id" column and just create a new SERIAL field or something like that?

QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibility 1: Delete the "id" field in the data you want to import before

Possibility 2: Define a new Primary Key: Tick the "Primary key" option and name it like "gid" or "fid" or whatever and after that delete the original "id" with double entries (or not).

Comment: The dialog does not make it clear at all that the Primary Key option allows the user to name the column that QGIS will **create*. I assumed this was selecting a column from the data-to-be-uploaded. Thanks!