# db manager shapefile import error

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, dbmanager

I am trying to import a shapefile using db manager to postgresql. My shapefile has OBJECTID (PRIMARY KEY), ID (STRING FIELD eg: 2543-96-7948 )and several other attributes of type string.
When importing I get the following error.

[image]

When I import using postgis shapefile import/export manager, I got no errors and the shapefile uploaded successfully.

I think qgis is assuming my primary key to be ID field when it is actually OBJECTID. How to change this?
I tried using the primary key field in input table and set it to id but got same error. Does it create new field or is it selecting a column from the attribute table?

looked up for answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288280/import-shapefile-to-postgis-in-qgis-db-manager-without-using-its-id-column) but was not enough to resolve my issue.

Comment: You should not set the primary key in input table into `id` because that is your problem. You have id field in your data with non-unique values. Name primary key into `foo` or anything else that you do not have in your attributes and the driver should use the objectid.

Comment: yes, that solved the issue. named the primary key to foo and it got imported.